# How to use nix-shell properly and avoid "dumping very large path"?

Tags: ocaml, nix

Based on my readings (notably [the wiki](https://nixos.org/wiki/Development_Environments) and [this blog post](http://datakurre.pandala.org/2015/10/nix-for-python-developers.html)), I have come up with the following `default.nix` that I load with `nix-shell`:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

let emacs =
  emacsWithPackages (p : [ p.tuareg ]);
in

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
    name = "env";

    src = ./.;

    # Customizable development requirements
    buildInputs = [
        pkgconfig
        ocaml
        ocamlPackages.merlin
        ocamlPackages.findlib
        ocamlPackages.lablgtk
        ocamlPackages.camlp5_transitional
        ncurses
        emacs
    ];

    # Customizable development shell setup
    shellHook = ''
        export PATH=`pwd`/bin:$PATH
    '';
}
```

But it always prints a warning:

```
warning: dumping very large path (> 256 MiB); this may run out of memory
```

and takes quite long to load (about 45 seconds the first time I call `nix-shell` after start-up, about 2 seconds on subsequent calls).

What is the meaning of this message? When I look for it on Google, I find a few GitHub issues but not expressed in a way that is easy to understand for the layman.

Can I speed up the load and remove this message? It seems to me that I'm doing something wrong.

Are there general recommendations on writing this kind of development environment that I might not be aware of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the `src` attribute (the current directory) is very big. `nix-shell` will copy it to the Nix store on each invocation, which is probably not what you want/need. The workaround is to write:

```
src = if lib.inNixShell then null else ./.;
```

(where `lib` comes from Nixpkgs).

This way, `./.` will be copied when you invoke `nix-build`, but not when you run `nix-shell`.

Comment: That was quite helpful. However, shouldn't it read `"then null else './.';"` instead of `"then null else nix;"`?

Comment: Wouldn't it cause the same warning to be issued when running `nix-build`?  That's the issue that I have even without use of `lib.inNixShell`, `nix-shell` is happy, but `nix-build` gives warning (but still works).

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but (since I can't comment on [niksnut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6747243/niksnut)'s [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39493330/11922937)) I wanted to mention a means of handling this if you want to add some subset of `src` to the Nix store, filtering out large/unneeded files.

This approach uses [`lib.cleanSource` and friends](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/943c10325bbb8cc49fc17d08d1ce190606d44c33/lib/sources.nix#L29-L51) from `nixpkgs`:

```
# shell.nix
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

with pkgs;

let
  cleanVendorFilter = name: type: 
    type == "directory" && baseNameOf (toString name) == "vendor";
  cleanVendor = src: lib.cleanSourceWith { filter = cleanVendorFilter; inherit src; };
  shellSrc = lib.cleanSource (cleanVendor ./.);
in mkShell {
  name = "my-shell";
  shellHook = ''
    printf 1>&2 '# Hello from store path %s!\n' ${shellSrc}
  '';
}
```

In the above snippet, `shellSrc` refers to an attribute set representing a store path that contains `./.`, but without the `vendor` subdirectory (`cleanVendor`) and without `.git`, `.svn`, files ending in `~`, and other editor/VCS-related stuff (`cleanSource`).

Check out [lib/sources.nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/16bd66818a1056a6bdbe5cc545c7e7ec32bb9939/lib/sources.nix) for more ways to filter paths.

Comment: This is the right way to do it, but this answer looks overly complicated because it deals with a `vendor` directory which the OP doesn't mention. It would be better to show `src = lib.cleanSource ./.;` first and then show how more complex things can be done.